# How to integrate Paytm payment gateway in iOS(swift) project? Unable to create object of PGMerchantConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm payment gateway in iOS(swift) project. I added pods as per steps mentioned on "https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit"

**Step 0: is done**

Now next step is :

---

**Step 1: Merchant configuration**

`SDK` identifies each Merchant by `PGMerchantConfiguration` object. You can configure this anywhere in the code before the first transaction with necessary parameters. It requires only one time configuration. Since it is singleton Class, you may utilize the same for any transaction within your application.

```
Objective – C
```

//You will get default PGMerchantConfiguration object. By setting the below properties of object you can make a fully configured merchant object.

```
PGMerchantConfiguration *mc = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
```

---

However I am not getting what should I do as when I am trying to create object in swift like :

```
let obj = PGMerchantConfiguration()
```

I am unable to find "PGMerchantConfiguration"

Is there anything I am missing?
Do I need to create Bridging Header file ?(if yes then how to do it) 
If anyone knows any link for integrating Paytm Payment gateway in iOS (swift) where step by step work instruction is given then please share, I have done so much digging but unable to find any.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to set the bridging header for it. then you can invoke your object like this:

```
 var merchantConf = PGMerchantConfiguration.default()
```

Let's go step by step:

1) Download Library from [Github](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit)

2) Create a bridging header.h as follows:

[image]

[image]

3) Now in project Target, set bridging header to header.h

[image]

4) Drag and drop the contents of Paytm Sdk folder

[image]

5) Your header file should look like

[image]

Following all of the above steps, now you can create an Object

```
  var merchantConf = PGMerchantConfiguration.default()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This solved my problem, Thank you Bhavin for details explanation with screen shots. I still didn't finish complete integration, hope there will be no problem ahead. Thank you once again! I would have up vote this answer but I am unable to do so.

Comment: okay great. You can accept it as a correct answer, if you see that option. 
You are always welcome. happy coding :)